# latest react-hook-form error handling with material-ui TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have difficulties, using react-hook-form with material-ui.

I prepared a [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-chandrasekhar-ppv46?file=/src/App.tsx).

```js
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";

interface IMyForm {
  vasarlo: string;
}

export default function App() {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
    register
  } = useForm<IMyForm>();

  const onSubmit = (data: IMyForm) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label>First Name</label>
      <TextField
        variant="outlined"
        margin="none"
        label="Test"
        {...register("vasarlo", {
          required: "error text"
        })}
        error={errors?.vasarlo ? true : false}
        helperText={errors?.vasarlo ? errors.vasarlo.message : null}
      />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

How can I properly use the register function, to get error message, write to input field, also the `onSubmit` function to work?

I couldn't find answer in the documentation for this scenario.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `react-hook-form` v7, this is how you register an input:

```js
<input {...register('name')} />
```

Calling `register()` will return necessary props for your input like `onChange`, `onBlur` and `ref`. These props make it possible for `react-hook-form` to keep track of your form data. Now when you use `register` with Material-UI `TextField` like this:

```js
<TextField {...register('name')} />
```

You pass the `ref` property directly to the `TextField` while the correct place to put it is in the `inputRef`:

```js
<TextField inputRef={ref} />
```

So you have to modify your code like this:

```js
const { ref: inputRef, ...inputProps } = register("vasarlo", {
  required: "error text"
});
```

```js
<TextField inputRef={inputRef} {...inputProps} />
```

> How can I properly use the register function, to get error message

There is nothing wrong with your error handling code. Though you can shorten you code a bit more using Typescript's [*optional chaining operator*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) `?.`:

```js
<TextField
  error={!!errors.vasarlo}
  helperText={errors?.vasarlo?.message}
  inputRef={ref}
  {...inputProps}
/>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67009085/latest-react-hook-form-error-handling-with-material-ui-textfield]

Comment: ah, well that will help me with my v7 upgrade, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing Controller. react-hook-form's default functionality is using uncontrolled inputs. Remove `<Controller/>` and put this on your TextField

```
inputRef={register({
    required: 'This is required',
    validate: (data) => myValidationFunction(data)
})}
```

You'll only want to use a controller if you NEED to modify/intercept/format a value that is being displayed in the TextField that is different from what a user is typing, i.e a phone number getting shown as (xxx)-xxx-xxxx when only typing the digits.

Comment: Ah realizing i'm a version behind, my syntax is out of date, let me look into it

Comment: Okay, I removed the controller part, and now I can type, and get onSubmit, but without value, also no error message...

Comment: Thanks acaputo. For me, this does the same thing as with v7. No value, also no error message.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-swartz-qn10b?file=/src/App.tsx Here's a working v6 example, i'll try and figure out v7 @Ebadta