# undefined errors object in react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm having this issue of

> Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.

I already follow the sample code on the documentation of `react-hook-form` but I'm still having this issue.

```
const [taskInfo, setTaskInfo] = useState({
    title: '',
    description: '',
    created: currentUser.fullname,
    assigned: '',
    priority: '',
    dateDue: new Date(),
  });


const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setTaskInfo((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  };


const { register, errors, handleSubmit } = useForm();

<TextField
  fullWidth
  variant='outlined'
  label='Title'
  value={taskInfo.title}
  onChange={handleChange}
  onFocus={handleDisbleLabel}
  onBlur={handleEnableLabel}
  InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}
  {...register('title', { required: 'This is required' })}
/>
  {errors.title && 'Your input is required'}
```

Comment: Where is taskInfo defined?

Answer (score 19):

If you are using `react-hook-form` v7, the `errors` object is moved to `formState` now, change your code to:

```
const { register, formState: { errors }, handleSubmit } = useForm();
```

Instead of

```
const { register, errors } = useForm();
```

Reference: [migrate-v6-to-v7](https://react-hook-form.com/migrate-v6-to-v7/).

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I overlook the link of the documentation that i'm reading, it's for version 6 not version 7.

Comment: Sir, how can solve the issue in terms of onChange? I can't type anything on the text field. Because I need to insert the name attribute but after inserting the attribute the issue still remains.

Comment: @rjc30 Sorry, somehow I missed your first comment, you need to pass the `ref` to `inputRef` props of `TextField`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67015773/9449426), it's the same problem except the author uses v7.

Comment: I saw your recommendation but i can't understand how i can apply those code into my logic. I updated the code above to show how many onchange works

Comment: @rjc30 are you using `react-hook-form` v7 or v6. Because the code in your question `...register()` is from v7. Also why do you need to control the form value by calling `setState()`, `react-hook-form` handles that for you internally, if you want to access the form values, use [`getValues()`](https://react-hook-form.com/v6/api#getValues) method instead.

Comment: I thought my old validation code will work on v7. But I saw there are lots of changes. Maybe i will stick with the v6 for now. Thanks for the help sir!!!

Comment: @rjc30 Here is a tip: you will get help a lot quicker from other people if you can provide a demo (codepen, codesandbox...) in your question. The live example from `react-hook-form` docs uses codesandbox so you may want to fork it and reproduce your problem.