# I am not able to get component value with Mui and ReactHookForm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm having problem to integrate React Hook Form with MUI's TextField, the screen doesn't render.

I'm using MUI version: `5.10.4` and React Hook Form   `7.36.1`.

I'm trying to capture the input values and print it on the console with onSubmit, but I'm not able to

Code:

```
import { Button, Grid, Typography } from '@mui/material';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';





const CreateOrUpdateJob = () => {
   
    const {register, handleSubmit, control, reset} = useForm();

    const onSubmit = (data: any) => console.log(data);
    

    return (
        <>
            <Typography
                variant="h2"
                color="initial"
                sx={{
                    marginTop: '1rem',
                    marginBottom: '1rem',
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    fontSize: '1.5rem',
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontWeight: '700'
                }}
            >
                Adicionar Vaga
            </Typography>
            <Grid
                container
                spacing={0}
                direction="column"
                alignItems="center"
                justifyContent="center"
                sx={{
                    minHeight: '100vh',
                    gap: '1rem'
                    // background opacity  0.5
                }}
            >
                <form
                    action=""
                    style={{
                        display: 'grid',
                        gap: '1rem',
                        width: '100%',
                        maxWidth: '1440px',
                        padding: '0 1rem',
                        margin: '0 auto'
                    }}
                >
                    <Controller
                        name="jobName"
                        defaultValue=""
                        control={control}
                        render={({ field:{onChange, value}}) => (
                            <TextField
                                label="Name Job"
                                id="jobName"
                                name="jobName"
                                value={value}
                                onChange={onChange}
                                variant="outlined"
                                fullWidth
                                inputRef={register}
                              
                            />
                        )}
                    />


                    <Button variant="contained" color="success" size="large" type="submit" fullWidth
                        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                    >
                        Criar vaga
                    </Button>
                    <Button variant="contained" color="success" size="large" type="submit" fullWidth
                        onClick={() => {
                            reset();
                        }}
                        >
                        Reset
                    </Button>
                </form>
            </Grid>
        </>
    );
};



export default CreateOrUpdateJob
```

Console Error:

When I enter inputRef={register} in the TextField, I can't capture the input values and it returns this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: path.split is not a function
    at get (get.ts:11:1)
    at register (createFormControl.ts:923:1)
    at setRef (setRef.js:16:1)
    at useForkRef.js:15:1
    at setRef (setRef.js:16:1)
    at useForkRef.js:16:1
    at commitAttachRef (react-dom.development.js:20875:1)
    at commitLayoutEffects (react-dom.development.js:23431:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
get @ get.ts:11
register @ createFormControl.ts:923
setRef @ setRef.js:16
(anonymous) @ useForkRef.js:15
setRef @ setRef.js:16
(anonymous) @ useForkRef.js:16
commitAttachRef @ react-dom.development.js:20875
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23431
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945




Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:20085
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:20118
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:12318
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:12339
commitLifeCycles @ react-dom.development.js:20736
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:23426
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
```

Comment: There is no `path.split` in your snippet, where is this error occurring?

Comment: When I enter inputRef={register} in the TextField, I can't capture the input values and it returns this error

Comment: Solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67009085/latest-react-hook-form-error-handling-with-material-ui-textfield